# Change the Image Margins of a Toggler Dynamically

Tags: palettes

I am making a unit palette for myself in Mathematica 11.3, and am planning on making a column of togglers for the sections.

```
Toggler[
  Text[Style["Physics Constants", 24, Italic]],
  {Text[Style["Physics Constants", 24, Italic]], 
   Column[{Text[Style["Physics Constants", 24, Italic]], physgrid}]}
]
```

Where `physgrid` is just a 4x4 grid of buttons. When I run this code, there is a huge margin around the first state, which I don't want.

Essentially, I want to make an `OpenerView`, without the little triangle icon. So, if that could be made instead, that would also suffice.

Comment: Perhaps adding an image of what you see, as well as a definition of `physgrid`, could help others troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: You probably want to add the option `ImageSize->Automatic` to your `Toggler`.

Comment: @MarcoB I have physgrid defined up about 3 levels before it gets to something built-in to mathematica, and on a white background, it isn't easy to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @CarlWoll That worked, though I could have sworn previously it wasn't. Thank you